# How to prevent parent table row column size expanding in collapsible table in react material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I followed [this example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/#collapsible-table) to create a collapsible table in react material UI. The parent row has only a few columns while the child row has multiple columns. So, when I click on the drop-down button, the parent row is also expanding, and the column sizes are increasing. I wanted the column sizes of the parent row to be the same, could someone please tell how to achieve this?